# UIAutomation trying to close contextmenu

Tags: wpf, popup, automation, contextmenu

I am working on automating a WPF application. After I simulate a right click on some window a ContextMenu appears (this is as desired).
My problem is that I want to close the context menu after I selected the correct item.

my code for closing the context menu does not throw an error, but fails to close the window:

```
var contextMenu = windowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, contextMenuIdCondition);
if (contextMenu == null)
    continue;
int windowHandle = windowElement.Current.NativeWindowHandle;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Trying to close window {0}", windowHandle);
IntPtr hWnd = new IntPtr(windowHandle);
DestroyWindow(hWnd);
```

Please note:

- I am using P/Invoke to call DestroyWindow on User32.dll
- the window handle seems legitimate
- the code runs when the context menu is open and focused (previous code selected an item in the menu successfully)
- windowElement is the popup window
- I tried getting WindowPattern from windowElement, but it is not supported

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I know it is possible, maybe even easy, to do it with mouse clicks. I'm looking for a "cleaner" way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was elsewhere...

I tried to play a recording of a user opening a context menu, then checking a menu item.
my context menu is defined like this:

```
       <ContextMenu AutomationProperties.AutomationId="MainContextMenu" StaysOpen="True">
            <MenuItem Header="Checkable Command1" IsCheckable="True" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ContextCommand1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Checkable Command2" IsCheckable="True"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ContextCommand2" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Command 3"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ContextCommand3" />
            <MenuItem Header="Command 4"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ContextCommand4" />
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:ContextMenuLogBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ContextMenu>
```

When playing the recorded actions for checkable items, I acted on the TogglePattern of the item and not on the InvokePattern. This did not close the context menu.
When I switched to InvokePattern, the item gets checked/unchecked, and the context menu closes.

This is the code I use for selecting the ContextMenu Item:
(controlForAction is the ContextMenu, itemId  is the AutomationProperties.AutomationId fo the menu item I want)

```
        PropertyCondition menuItemCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuItem);
        Condition itemIdCondition = CreateAutomationIdCondition(itemId);
        Condition andCondition = new AndCondition(menuItemCondition, itemIdCondition);
        AutomationElement matchingItem = controlForAction.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, andCondition);

        if (matchingItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Failed to find context menu item for Id {0}", itemId));
        }

        // Important: if you choose another pattern (e.g., TogglePattern) - the context menu will not close
        object testedPattern;
        InvokePattern invokePattern;
        bool wasFound = matchingItem.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out testedPattern);
        if (wasFound && (invokePattern = testedPattern as InvokePattern) != null)
        {
            invokePattern.Invoke();
            return;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ContextMenuItem - no pattern found");

        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("could not find matching pattern for menu item {0}", itemId));
```